# Accessing description of node-mysql error

Tags: json, node.js, node-mysql

When my query or connection fails I get the error back as:

```
{ 
  [Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'am@xfiles.com' for key 'email_UNIQUE'] 
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY', 
  errno: 1062, 
  sqlState: '23000', 
  index: 0 
}
```

I can access the keys through `[object].[key]` notation but cannot seem to access the text with `[]`. I would like to get that as a description of the error.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax when error values are printed out will look like your example:

```
{[Error: message]}
```

You can access this property with `errorObject.message`

See the [documentation for `Error`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_message)

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the link. Answers a couple of other questions that were brewing !!